# Photosynthesis being a synthesis reaction

Tags: synthesis

If a synthesis reaction is a reaction in which two or more substances react together to form just one product, then how is it that photosynthesis has two products; glucose and oxygen?

Comment: Where did you get that definition of synthesis? It is not one I recognise. There is always more than one product from a synthetic reaction.

Comment: Did you encounter the word «byproduct»?  Its use is not limited to chemistry (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/By-product).

Comment: The school definition of synthesis is pretty much never used outside of school.

Comment: Photosynthesis is a most complex set of reactions, all of which occur in proteins and in the chloroplast cell membrane and have taken at least 50 years to sort out by numerous scientists.  Look for 'primary processes' and 'light reactions' in photosynthesis and the Calvin cycle for the dark reactions.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're being a little too strict with your definition of what a synthesis reaction is. A better way to describe it might be building more complex molecules from simpler ones.

Wouldn't you say $\ce{C6H12O6}$ is more complex than $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$?